# A problem on double slit experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, double-slit-experiment

The setup of double slit experiment is shown, find the minimum value of *d* for which *O* is the brightest point.
I've tried to solve this using one method, but the answer don't match. The solution manual suggests that i use Pythagoras theorem and then finally binomial expansion to determine the path difference. I want to know where i'm wrong.
The answer should be: ((lambda)*D)^(1/2)
[image: the setup]
[image: my solution:]

Comment: Can't spot the exact problem offhand, but I think that there is a problem with the trigonometry and small-angle approximations you're using. If I just use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the the total path difference for the two paths shown, then I get $d^2/D$, which is half the value that you got. Using $d^2/D$ for the total path length and setting it equal to $\lambda$ results in the same answer as in your solution manual. Try using the Pythagorean theorem directly rather than using trigonometry and small angle approximations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's the problem. First of all, the $d\sin\theta$ is only meant to be an approximation, but that's not the important thing to know. The most important thing is that it is an approximation that works *only* when the screen is so far away that the two paths are nearly parallel.

In this situation, the problem explicitly says that the two paths have a non-negligible angle $\theta$ to each other. Therefore, you can't invoke the $d\sin\theta$ *by design of the problem.*

You'd have to use Samuel Weir's suggestion and look at the path length difference directly using the Pythagorean Theorem.

The bottom path has length $2D$ and the top path has length $2\sqrt{d^{2}+D^{2}}$. The path difference is 
$$2\sqrt{d^{2}+D^{2}}-2D = 2D\left( \sqrt{1+\tfrac{d^{2}}{D^{2}}}-1 \right) \approx 2D\left( \left(1+\tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{d^{2}}{D^{2}}\right) -1 \right) = \frac{d^{2}}{D}. $$

As you already realized, you want the path difference to be $d^{2}/D = \lambda$ so then $d = \sqrt{\lambda D}$.

---

You can see the issues a little more clearly if you actually look at an accurate representation of the setup and compare the two paths with a circle/compass.

[image: Comparing paths exactly]

If you look closely, you'll see that the blue line and the diagonal black line do not form a right angle, so assuming a path difference of $d\sin\theta$ wouldn't work.

However, like I already said, the real problem is that the two paths are not near parallel. That is what prevents us from invoking the $d\sin\theta$ approximation.